# tourist visa UK

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, canadian-citizens

My Canadian girlfriend and my 5 month old daughter are coming to the UK.

I know they can stay for 6 months and then have to leave the UK. Is it possible for the 3 of us to go to Germany for a holiday when the UK visitors visa ends, and then reenter the UK with a fresh 6 months visitors visa?

I am a UK citizen with a British passport. My girlfriend and child both have Canadian passports.

Comment: As an aside, note that your daughter is likely *also* a British citizen herself, particularly if you (her father) were born in the UK. See [Apply for citizenship if you have a British parent](https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-british-parent/born-on-or-after-1-july-2006) for more information.

Comment: For reference, see https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Answer (score 4):

**No, they cannot do this.**

One of the things you cannot do with a visitor visa, or with visa-free entry, is use successive 'visits' to effective live in the UK. If you try this, your girlfriend and daughter will almost certainly be turned away at the border when you return from Germany. They will then have a record of being refused entry which will cause problems trying to visit many countries in the future.

If they want to live with you in the UK, the only way to do that is to apply for a residence visa of some kind. Questions about that belong on our sister site [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).